# IText don't find image in the specified path when .NET application is built in linux

Tags: c#, .net, image, pdf, itext

I have the following code in .NET 7 to find an image that i use in my PDF file:

```
private static Image GetImage(string imageName, int width, int height)
{
    var imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create($"Utils\\Images\\{imageName}.png");

    return new Image(imageData)
          .SetWidth(width)
          .SetHeight(height);
}
```

All works fine in local environment, but when i publish my application to linux-armx64, the image is not found. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: In general when working on linux or unix.  Make sure to use Path.Combine or Path.Join, and make sure to use correct casing everywhere. Also check working directory, use `Path.GetFullPath` to ensure you are actually looking where you think you are.